# css page high automatic and leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I have troubles with the automatic high of a page when using leaflet (javascript). Does anyone has an idea how to set a fix page high just for one site? or any other ideas to fix this?

CSS Page:

```
#inhalt {
  height: auto;
  background-image: url(images/fv1.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #979696;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-family: tahoma, verdana, arial, helvetica, verdana, tahoma, sans-serif;
  border-left: solid 1px #fff;
}
```

CSS map:

```
#map {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 180px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}

html,
body,
#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 750px;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: could you show us some parts of your code please? How can people help you without seeing what you have already tried?

Comment: Sorry, just don't know which part of the code is important!? I just played around with the settings of the css. – I can give a link to the page, maybe that would help?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="map"></div>
#map { height: 180px; }
```

Have a look at: http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html
that should fix your problem.

Comment: :-/ the map high is defined.

Comment: CSS Page: `#inhalt {height:auto;background-image:url(images/fv1.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-position:  0% 0%;
background-color:#fff;
text-align:left;
vertical-align:top;
padding-top: 50px; padding-bottom: 30px;
padding-left: 30px;padding-right:30px;
letter-spacing:0px;
width:100%;
color:#979696;
font-size: 15px;line-height: 22px;
font-family: tahoma,verdana,arial,helvetica, verdana, tahoma, sans-serif;
border-left: solid 1px #fff;
}`

Comment: CSS map: `#map { display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top:10px;
height:180px;
width:100%; 
 background-color:#000;}
html, body, #map {
 height: 500px;
 width: 750px;
}
th {
 text-align: left;
 vertical-align: top;
}`

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to achieve from this. You first set the Map's height to 180px and then you set html, body, #map ``{ height: 500px; width: 750px; }``. What height you want your map element?
Can you also attach the html code for that?

Comment: yes...thats strange – I don't want any specific high. I just want the map to appear when the CSS of the main php/html-Site sets the high automatically. But the map disappears when its 'height:auto' – Also: I haven't got any html code for the map. It's all javascript and there is no set for high (only in the css)

Comment: Probably that's the problem. You need to create a ``<div id="map"></div>`` if you want the map to be rendered in the page

Comment: To make it clear: the problem appears just when i set 'high:auto' in the main CSS document.